How Do I Pass JSON Data in the Desktop Version of Power Automate?
This sanitized cURL query works fine [1]:
curl -X POST https://adb-<workspaceId>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <myPersonalAccessToken>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "warehouse_id": "<myWareHouseId>",                                                                                     
  "catalog": "hive_metastore",                                                                                            
  "schema": "dev.bronze",                                                                                              
  "statement": "SELECT * FROM dev.bronze.shawn_test_table;"
}'

Unfortunately, when I try to put the cURL command into the desktop version of Power Automate, I get the error:
{"error_code":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Invalid JSON given in the body of the request - failed to parse given JSON"}

What am I doing wrong in Power Automate?
[1] - Various AI engines helped write that query.
[2] - See Also: Arrogant Sage Media, "Power Automate Desktop - Connect to API, Read & Process JSON & Create and Post JSON", YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSWqw8kJYrw ,
June 14, 2023, Last Visited: August 23, 2024

what are trying to do here? are you trying to execute your script using REST API?

@RakeshGovindula - I'm trying to run the cURL command shown above in Microsoft Power Automate. The cURL command has been sanitized to remove sensitive information, but it works fine. The problem is I can't get the Invoke Web Service step of MS Power Automate to work.

Eventually, Microsoft Copilot clued me in on the problem by telling me more than once to check the "Encode Request Body" option. It suggested that I turn the option on, but ironically, the solution was to turn the feature off.

You will find the "Encode request body" switch in the Advanced section on the current version of Power Automate.
The setting was apparently on by default for my program.
